# Jest: Creating promise rejections in beforeEach causes errors in tests that don't call the handling code

Tags: javascript, jestjs

In the following example, I create and mock a service upon which I set some manually mocked behaviour, namely a `Promise.reject` for the first call, and a `Promise.resolve` for the second.

I've simplified my code for this example down to just two tests, which are both related so therefore live in the same `describe` block.

The first test calls the code that handles the promise rejection and therefore everything runs fine.

The second test is currently empty, but imagine a scenario where it doesn't call the same bit of code that handles the promise rejection. In both these cases (the hypothetical and the empty test) running the tests results in the following error:
`UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection (rejection id: 15): Error: Oh noes!`

This is a particular problem when running `npm run test` in a CRA, since the unhandled rejection causes the watching jest command to stop with an unhelpful error message ('Oh noes!') and no relevant stack trace.

I know I can get round this by moving the manual mock that creates a rejection to inside the first test, but I want that setup block to be used for several other tests and it doesn't seem like I should have to create another describe block just for those that depend on this.

Is there a better way to avoid this problem?

My original problem happened in a CRA which is on Jest v20, but I've recreated using the below in Jest v21 and v22.

**myService.js**

```
const doSomething = () => {
  return 'foo';
};

export { doSomething };
```

**myService.spec.js**

```
import * as myService from '../myService';

jest.mock('../myService');

describe('Demonstration of unhandled promise rejection', () => {
  const mockRefreshError = new Error('Oh noes!');
  mockRefreshError.status = 401;

  const mockResponse = { body: 'hello, world' };

  beforeEach(() => {
    myService.doSomething = jest
      .fn()
      .mockReturnValueOnce(Promise.reject(mockRefreshError))
      .mockReturnValueOnce(Promise.resolve(mockResponse));
  });

  it('should catch the rejection and get the expected error message', async () => {
    await expect(myService.doSomething()).rejects.toHaveProperty(
      'message',
      'Oh noes!'
    );
  });

  it('should cause an unhandled rejection despite not doing anything', () => {});
});
```

**Output of `npm run test`:**

```
(node:54711) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection (rejection id: 4): Error: Oh noes!
PASS  jest-mocks/__tests__/myModule.spec.js
  Demonstration of unhandled promise rejection
    ✓ should catch the rejection and get the expected error message (1ms)
    ✓ should cause and unhandled rejection despite not doing anything

Test Suites: 1 passed, 1 total
Tests:       2 passed, 2 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        0.14s, estimated 1s
Ran all test suites related to changed files.

Watch Usage: Press w to show more.
```

Comment: You can also use `mockRejectedValueOnce`

Comment: @J.Pichardo that's just a sugar function for what the code above is doing and causes the same problem. Also, I don't believe it's available in Jest v20.

Comment: That's right, and sorry I missed the version

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This looks like it [was discovered](https://github.com/facebook/jest/issues/5721) and fixed with [a PR (#5720) that's been merged to master](https://github.com/facebook/jest/pull/5720), but [is yet to be released](https://github.com/facebook/jest/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md) (i.e. it comes after v22.4.2).

Still open to suggestions if someone can think of a better way to handle this other than putting those tests in a separate `describe` block with its own `beforeEach`, or as a one-line method call in each test that needs it. Both feel a little extraneous.